# Delete Laravel 5.3 polymorphic items when deleting parent via cascade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphism

I'm trying to delete polymorphic items/relationships when a parent is deleted.

My structure is;

```
- User (hasMany: Page)
- - Page (hasMany: Module, belongsTo: User)
- - - - Module (belongsTo: Page, morphTo: content())
- - - - - ModuleVideo (morphMany: 'content')
- - - - - ModuleAudio (morphMany: 'content')
- - - - - ModuleSomething (morphMany: 'content')
```

I can delete the Module and ModuleItem by pinging `Module` directly;

```
$module->forceDelete();
$module->content->forceDelete();
```

The `User > Page > Module` are all setup so `onDelete` they cascade down.

How do I force `ModuleVideo/Audio/Something` to delete if any of the parents (`Page` or `User`) are deleted?

Comment: Can you please clarify a little your issue? I didn't understand the last sentence, is it question or just an information?

Comment: I've slightly reworded it: How do I force `ModuleItem` to delete if any of the parents (`Page` or `User`) are deleted?

Comment: Where is ModuleItem in you current relations? Is it ModuleVideo / Audio / Something ?

Comment: That's correct. There are multiple different ModuleTypes that morph to a parent Module

Comment: But only one ModuleItem at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a trait like this

```
 trait Cascadable {

 public static function bootCascade()
 {
  static::deleting(function ($model) {
    if (property_exists($model, 'cascade') && is_array($model->cascade)) {
      foreach ($model->getCascade() as $relation) {
        if (method_exists($model, $relation)) {
          foreach ($model->{$relation}()->get() as $related)
            $related->delete();
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

protected function getCascade() {
  return $this->cascade;
}
```

And use in your classes by defining protected $cascade variable in each class

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a through this evening. Do I use this Trait in the Module class?

Comment: Yes, you can create a ModelItem class that will extend Model and use Cascadable trait, then all your items classes extend ModelItem class

Comment: I'll give that a try